# How to block text field when user change database from drop down menu?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have GUI app to connect with few databases and from every database I use different fields to connect. The main question is how I can disable fields depending on which database user will choose, for example like in the below picture when user chooses MySQL, fields like dbName and path to db are disabled.

[image]

But when user will choose other, for example SQLite, fields like localhost, port, username and password should be disabled. For now I disabled fields for MySQL but when I change to other databases the same fields are still disabled.

Below is my code:

```
private void choseFieldsWhichNeedToDb() {
    String value = databaseChoiceBox.getValue();
    if (value.equals("MySql")){
        databaseNameTextField.setDisable(true);
        databasePathTextField.setDisable(true);
    }
}

private void fillChoiceBox() {
    DatabaseType[] types = DatabaseType.values();
    for (DatabaseType type : types) {
        databaseChoiceBox.getItems().add(type.getType());
    }
    databaseChoiceBox.setValue("MySql");
}
```

Comment: So enable the fields (e.g. `field.setDisable(false)`) when the user chooses a different database?

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer but hopefully enough to allow you to complete your app.

You need to create a `ChangeListener` that listens to changes in the `ChoiceBox` selected value and enable or disable the relevant `TextField`s according to the chosen value in the `ChoiceBox`.

The below code creates a GUI similar to that in your screen capture but only enables (or disables) the *dbName* and *path* text fields according to the selected database.

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ChooseDb extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        root.setHgap(10.0);
        root.setVgap(10.0);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));
        Label hostLabel = new Label("Host");
        root.add(hostLabel, 0, 0);
        TextField hostTextField = new TextField();
        root.add(hostTextField, 1, 0);
        Label portLabel = new Label("Port");
        root.add(portLabel, 2, 0);
        TextField portTextField = new TextField();
        root.add(portTextField, 3, 0);
        Label usernameLabel = new Label("Username");
        root.add(usernameLabel, 0, 1);
        TextField usernameTextField = new TextField();
        root.add(usernameTextField, 1, 1);
        Label passwordLabel = new Label("Password");
        root.add(passwordLabel, 2, 1);
        TextField passwordTextField = new TextField();
        root.add(passwordTextField, 3, 1);
        Label dbNameLabel = new Label("Database name");
        root.add(dbNameLabel, 0, 2);
        TextField dbNameTextField = new TextField();
        dbNameTextField.setDisable(true);
        root.add(dbNameTextField, 1, 2);
        Label dbPathLabel = new Label("Path to database file");
        root.add(dbPathLabel, 2, 2);
        TextField dbPathTextField = new TextField();
        dbPathTextField.setDisable(true);
        root.add(dbPathTextField, 3, 2);
        ChoiceBox<String> dbNames = new ChoiceBox<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList("MySQL", "SQLite"));
        dbNames.setValue("MySQL");
        dbNames.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,
                                String oldValue,
                                String newValue) {
                switch (newValue) {
                    case "MySQL":
                        dbNameTextField.setDisable(true);
                        dbPathTextField.setDisable(true);
                        break;
                    case "SQLite":
                        dbNameTextField.setDisable(false);
                        dbPathTextField.setDisable(false);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        root.add(dbNames, 0, 3);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I added the listener but when I launch the app and default value is equal MySQL all fields are possible to fill

Comment: @mroma you need to initially set the disabled fields to match the initial `ChoiceBox` selection. Notice in my code that I initially set the `dbNameTextField` to disabled.